# Jenkins access files from other repo

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have two separate repos in Jenkins, foo: containing code, and bar: containing unit tests relevant to foo's code.  They're in separate repos because bar is heavy and contains a lot of unit tests.

I want my workflow to look something like this:

1. Update code in foo, add unit tests to bar
2. Pull rebase in both repos
3. Run unit test code in bar, while being in foo's directory (to reference environmental variables.)

How can I do this in Jenkins?  Is this even a good workflow?
The point of this is to run unit tests in bar while using code in foo.

Comment: in my personal experience it is not a good workflow at all, though it is your choice. 
Can you please share how you execute your tests from ```bar``` in your local machine ?

Comment: @BigGinDaHouse You're right, this is not a good workflow.  Instead I'm going to do this a different way.  I'm going to git clone bar into a subdirectory of foo during the build instead.